# Access Violation in C# - winmm.dll ntdll.dll

Tags: c#, access-violation, winmm

I have an application which basically does three things:

1. Show an image to the user
2. Play a 1-2 second sound (wav) to the user
3. Record microphone input for 4 seconds (while sound is playing)

This happens 280 times per user, and all of the recordings are saved in a directory for each user. However, 2 out of the last 18 runs of the program, it crashed from an unhandled exception with code c0000005 (which is described as an access violation) in module ntdll.dll. The only unmanaged api call I'm using is mciSendString from winmm.dll to get the duration of wav files and do the recording. Playback is done using an instance of WindowsMediaPlayer.

The crashes seem to be random, and both happened on the same machine (3 are being used). These are my questions: Is ntdll.dll really the source of the exception? Am I correct in understanding the access violation is an invalid memory access? And how could that happen with a C# program running in the .NET virtual machine?

By request here is one class from which I invoke mciSendString

```
public class JE_SR
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "mciSendStringA", 
        CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern uint mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, 
        string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);

    [DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int mciGetErrorString(uint errorCode, 
        StringBuilder errorText, int errorTextSize);


    private static bool recording = false;
    public static uint lastResult;

    public static void startRecording()
    {
        if (recording)
        {
            return;
        }

        tryMCISendString("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0);
        tryMCISendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0);

        recording = true;
    }

    public static void stopRecording(string file)
    {
        if (!recording)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!file.Equals(""))
        {
            tryMCISendString("save recsound " + file, "", 0, 0);
            tryMCISendString("close recsound ", "", 0, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            tryMCISendString("close all", "", 0, 0);
        }

        recording = false;
    }

    public static void tryMCISendString(string lpstrCommand,
        string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback)
    {
        lastResult = mciSendString(lpstrCommand, lpstrReturnString, uReturnLength, hwndCallback);

        StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder(256);
        if(lastResult != 0)
        {
            mciGetErrorString(lastResult, error, error.Length);
            JE_Log.logMessage("MCIERROR(JE_SR): " + error.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if there are other relevant details I should include...

Comment: A source code of the way you have defined the P/Invoke signature and the way you are calling it might be helpful.

Comment: If the code is doing P/Invoke, you can't really say that the program is running in the .NET virtual machine (only). That's like saying "How can the prisoner do this when he's in jail (with an open door)"

Comment: We need a *native* call stack before we can figure out what's happening. To get this, download Debugging Tools for Windows, run WinDbg, "Attach to Process", then type '.symfix; kn100' into the command window

Comment: Although accurate, the sad part was comparing a .NET program to a prisoner...

Comment: @Lasse I know it's not running ONLY in the virtual machine. The thing that threw me off is the fact that the system log says the cause of the exception came from ntdll.dll, which goes back to my first question: is it even sensible for me to think that my use of winmm.dll is the cause?

Comment: @Paul I haven't been able to recreate the exception so I think that effort would be futile until I figure out how to make it fail on purpose

Comment: @JeffE Yes, it is entirely possible - if you pass garbage data to an ntdll func (indirectly, via winmm), it will AV

Comment: Got a stack trace from the last occurrence and it turns out it was really a null reference error caused by a variant of the off by one error (from a missing return statement inside of an if clause). This was after changing the mciSendString declaration as suggested below. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2):

One problem is this:

```
private static extern uint mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, 
        string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);
```

That last value should be `IntPtr`. Otherwise it's not going to work in the 64-bit runtime and it's possible that something could step on the stack. Change that to `IntPtr` and pass `IntPtr.Zero'.

Also, the `lpstrReturnString` parameter is there for you to pass a pointer to a buffer that will receive returned data. Passing an empty string here is a bad idea, because `mciReturnString` might try to store data in that string. That could give you an access violation or, worse, overwrite something critical. If you don't need error information returned, then either change that to `IntPtr` and pass `IntPtr.Zero`, or use a `StringBuilder`. See http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winmm.mcisendstring for the correct definition.

And, yes, it makes perfect sense for ntdll.dll to be the source of the exception, since it's likely that the functions in winmm.dll call functions that are in ntdll.dll. As others have said, you'll need a native stack trace to see exactly what's happening.

Comment: So I know this is many years later, but I just want to tell you that this was the exact issue it turned out I had in a library I used, and now I can finally use it with .Net Framework 4+. Before I was limited to 3.5 for some reason. Thank you so much! ^^